# adding a null column to s selection in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi is is possible to get a null column in sqlalchemy? For example I would like to select all user ids together with a NULL column

```
db.session.query(models.User.id, NULL)
```

The reason for this is that I need to do a UNION, which requires the same number of columns...
thanks
fl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.null](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html?#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.null)

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import null
db.session.query(models.User.id, null())
```